# logback's RollingFileAppender is not rolling file with EvaluatorFilter

Tags: logback, rollingfileappender

Logback framework's **ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender** is not rolling files when **EvaluatorFilter** is used as following:

```
<appender name="APPLICATION-INFO"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.root}/${CONTEXT_NAME}-INFO.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.root}/${CONTEXT_NAME}-INFO-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator> 
            <expression>return (level == INFO || level == WARN);</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="com.xxx.yyyy.zzz.logging.json.JsonLayout">
            <timestampFormat>${timestampFormat}</timestampFormat>
            <includeMDC>false</includeMDC>
        </layout>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

But the the following configuration rolls the log file.

```
<appender name="APPLICATION-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.root}/${CONTEXT_NAME}-ERROR.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.root}/${CONTEXT_NAME}-ERROR-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.logging.json.JsonLayout">
            <timestampFormat>${timestampFormat}</timestampFormat>
            <includeMDC>false</includeMDC>
        </layout>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit lazy to test that locally but I have a clue what might be wrong :-) In the [docs of logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) it is written:

> For various technical reasons, rollovers are not clock-driven but
>   depend on the arrival of logging events. For example, on 8th of March
>   2002, assuming the fileNamePattern is set to yyyy-MM-dd (daily
>   rollover), the arrival of the first event after midnight will trigger
>   a rollover. If there are no logging events during, say 23 minutes and
>   47 seconds after midnight, then rollover will actually occur at
>   00:23'47 AM on March 9th and not at 0:00 AM.

Based on this a possible guess is that there was no proper logging event accepted by the default [JaninoEventEvaluator](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#JaninoEventEvaluator) that you configured.

Another speculation is that you do not refer the appender properly but there are not enough details about this in the question.